# MSAL System.InvalidOperationException: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL for .NET to acquire tokens for my Graph API requests, but out of sudden, I'm getting following error, which I can see a lot of post about, but no solution of reason why Error 80049217 happens? Does anyone know why this error occurs and maybe a solution to avoid the error?

> System.InvalidOperationException: CompactToken parsing failed with
> error code: 80049217

UPDATE 22-01-10
Example of method to acquire access token (Client is instance of HttpClient reused by all threads using the factory class containing this method. _confidentialClient is an instance of IConfidentialClientApplication in the MSAL .NET library):

```
private IConfidentialClientApplication _confidentialClient;

public void Initialize()
{
    // Construct the ConfidentialClientApplication
    _confidentialClient = 
        ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("clientId")
            .WithClientSecret("clientSecret")
            .WithAuthority("authority")
            .Build();
}

// Multiple threads will access this method
private async Task GetAccessToken()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Acquire token....");
        // Is the .AcquireTokenForClient method thread safe??
        var result = await _confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default").ExecuteAsync();
        if(Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization?.Parameter == result.AccessToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Token havn't changed.");
            return;
        }
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        Console.WriteLine("Acquire token successfully!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

All threads interacting with Graph API by this factory class will start by calling the GetAccessToken method to make sure the HttpClient has a valid AccessToken in the Authorization header. As far as I have read about IConfidentialClientApplication, the AcquireTokenForClient() will look for valid tokens in the internal cache, and if there isn't any, acquiring a new one, which is why the method is always invoked by any thread.

UPDATE 22-01-13:
Added some logic of how the IConfidentialClientApplication is built.

Comment: Could you pls show us how you generate the access token? Code snippet or which tutorial you followed? I'm afraid there's something wrong with your code then it made the token you obtained is not a correct token.

Comment: @TinyWang I have updated with a sample of how I do acquire access tokens, using the IConfidentialClientApplication interface of MSAL.NET library. The application run for several hours acquirering new tokens etc. without any exceptions, and suddenly (I cannot see the pattern as I don't know what triggers the CompactToken error) it breaks into the CompactToken exception.

Comment: It seemed that you wrote this code in your asp.net core backend project, and you wanna a method to help generate access token for different scopes without entering user name/password to sign in, so that it can serve different scenario. But you made a mistake here. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?view=azure-dotnet#parameters) first. In a server/daemon application, you can only use client credential flow to generate access token, so the scope for graph api should be

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` but  not the one you write as `user.read`. Maybe [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) can help you.

Comment: @TinyWang Sorry that was a typo, the scope was of cause .default already (edited the code snippet). And yes, your assumptions about the application is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, and if you have further concern on this question, please feel free to update here, and if you think this case can end now, if you can pick my post as the answer? Thanks in advance. @grmihel

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that you wrote this code in your asp.net core backend project, and you wanna a method to help generate access token for different scopes without entering user name/password to sign in, so that it can serve different scenario. But you made a mistake here.

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?view=azure-dotnet#parameters) first. In a server/daemon application, you can only use **client credential flow** to generate access token, so the scope for graph api should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, and [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) provides the sample code to use client credential flow in your asp.net core app. Here's the snippet.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "common";
// Values from app registration
var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

Comment: I updated the original post with the way my app is using the client to acquire access tokens, using the IConfidentialClientApplication of Microsoft.Identity.Client namespace. The applications is not using Azure.Identity nor Microsoft.Graph packages.

Comment: You can also using `var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;` to get access token. Then you don't need to use graph sdk. But it still use Azure.Identity package.

Comment: I have no ideas about how to use `IConfidentialClientApplication` as I never use it. Sorry,'